# Dynamically resizing UICollectionViewCell while editing content

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm kind of stuck with a problem here.
So, I've got a **UICollectionView with a textView inside**. The problem is, that I need to **change the collectionViewCell's height** and therefor it's y-position in the collectionView if I'm adding a line of text to the textView. Unfortunately, everything I tried doesn't work. Here's what it looks like:

(I'm not allowed to post full size screenshots)

[image: Ss]

**Green = collectionViewBackground, black = cell's background**

Does somebody know how to make the green disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your viewcontroller implements **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**
and override the sizeForItemAt function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let data: String = list[indexPath.row] //Your data for specific index
    let size = data.size(attributes: nil)
    return size
}
```

This should help you resolve your problem and don't forget to set **collectionview.delegate = self** //Your view Controller

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try that!